# How to give space between rows of a table

Tags: views, theming

I have a [view in Drupal](http://www.pepitablanca.com/?q=shop) and I want to give more space between elements rows. How do I do it?

Comment: You should learn some basic CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a basic CSS question, just use `padding` or `margin` and the view row class as the selector.

Consider outputting the view as an HTML list instead, and not as an HTML table, because with standard HTML tables these things become a bit tricky to do (and it's not recommended)

Comment: Hi Pere, thanks four your comments. The view has the grid format. It's very trick to do?

Comment: I saw that was an html table, just use the list style (you will need to theme some things again, though)